# Stream MKV from NAS over AV receiver to HD projector

Tags: nas, hdmi, video-streaming, dlna

I need to know how to stream videos files (MKV, AVI etc.).

This is my setup:

1. NAS: Synology DiskStation 112j with DSM 4.2 <-- this is where my videos are stored
2. AV-Receiver: Denon AVR 2313
3. HD Projector

Right now and since my AV receiver (and many others) cannot stream videos I just connect my laptop to my AV receiver (via HDMI) and just open the movie via VLC player on my laptop.

What I want to achieve is: Stream videos to my projector over AVR conviently without a laptop.

How can I do that? Do I need another device? Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pretty much same setup and looking for a good solution myself.
my suggestion :
HDD/NAS/any disks on your home network---Network Media Player----A/V Receiver---Projector

This in theory will allow you to stream audio/video from external drive connected directly to network player or from NAS or any disks on your home network to multimedia player,HDMI out form that to your A/V receiver/ and out to projector.

Network Media Player 
e.g. cheaper option  WD TV Live with HDMI out.
or 
Qnap NMP-1000P 
http://www.qnap.com/uk/index.php?lang=en-uk&sn=5050&c=2487&sc=2497&t=2522&n=14277

NO cant comment on any of these as i have not used it myself.
I have  Lacinema multimedia Hard Drive but its rubbish.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Network Media Tank, Media Streamer are other terms for the device your looking for.  The key bit when looking is confirm it supports the formats you have, MKV's being the least supported.